# MySQL php INSERT INTO ... SELECT: use commas to join $var+value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to use this php query:

```
INSERT INTO table1(id,picture) SELECT id, $var.picture from table2
```

Where $var is "http://example.com/images/".

Example (before):

```
ID = 1
picture = 'flower.jpg'
```

---

Example (after):

```
ID = 1
picture = 'http://example.com/images/flower.jpg'
```

How can I join in the SELECT $var and picture (the commas not working)...

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly this should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO table1(id,picture) SELECT id, CONCAT($var, picture) FROM table2
```

Comment: It generates a syntax error. So I used:
INSERT INTO table1(id,picture) SELECT id, CONCAT('http://example.com/images/', picture) FROM table2

Answer (score 0):

You could use `concat($var, '.picture')`.

However, you shouldn't do that.  Instead, you should pass the `$var` value as a parameter into query.  I would concatenate the value on the application side, but you can also use `concat()` with a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can perform it php-side. Simply instanciate a temporary variable which will contains your correctly formatted column using [sprintf()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php) :

```
// Get the data 
$id         =   1;
$var        =   'http://example.com/images/';
$picture    =   'flower.jpg';
$column     =   sprintf('%s%s', $var, $picture);

// Set the query
$query  =   sprintf('   INSERT INTO  table1 (id, picture)
                           SELECT       %s, %s
                           FROM         table2;', $id, $column);
```

Comment: As you do not use prepared query, I would also suggest to use `addslashes()` for your string in order to prevent misformatting error of query.